# how can i retrieve data by comparing current year in data flow task?

Tags: sql, ssis

```
select *, year(DOJ) year 
from source 
where year(DOJ) < =(select year(getdate())
                    from source) - 3
```

If I write code like this in the look-up transformation, I'm getting error as sub-query returning multiple values. so i just want to save the current year in a variable and use it in stead of a sub-query. But I'm unable to do that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Current year should be a constant value right? Why do you need to select from table?

Comment: yes. But I just got confused. So..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, YEAR(DOJ) year 
FROM source
WHERE YEAR(DOJ) <= YEAR(GETDATE()) - 3
```

You can directly use the `YEAR` function on `GETDATE` without the need for a subquery.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RDAIRX21218) on SQL Server here. I have also tested in an actual Lookup Transform in SSIS, but I can't post that here.

Comment: have you checked it??

Answer (score 1):

Your Subquery is wrong. You can try this rather:-

```
SELECT *, YEAR(DOJ) year 
FROM source
WHERE YEAR(DOJ) <= (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())) - 3
```